# plan shapes issue in dataframe concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i'm trying to concat dataframe df
[image]

to dataframe df_train

[image]

in each iteration

since i do not know the categories of df in advance i'm having hard time achieving the desired result as shown below

[image]

I have tried many approaches including

```
df_train = pd.concat([df_train,df],axis=0,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

or

```
df_train = df_train.append(df,sort=False)
```

However i'm getting

```
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:** This issue exist only when i convert my categorical data to numerical with

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df,prefix_sep='', prefix='')
```

however

```
df=pd.get_dummies(df) #does not pose same issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reproducing your image data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,0,23,0,0,1,0],
    [1,1,65,0,1,0,1],
    [4,2,34,1,0,0,0]
], columns=['Iteration', 'Player', 'Result', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'])

df_train = pd.DataFrame([
    [2,54,0,0,0,1,0],
    [2,87,1,0,1,0,1],
    [2,78,2,1,0,0,0]
], columns=['Iteration','Result','Player', 'cat3', 'cat1', 'cat9', 'cat8'])

df.head()
    Iteration   Player  Result  cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4
0   1   0   23  0   0   1   0
1   1   1   65  0   1   0   1
2   4   2   34  1   0   0   0

df_train.head()
    Result  Player  cat3    cat1    cat9    cat8
0   2   54  0   0   0   1   0
1   2   87  1   0   1   0   1
2   2   78  2   1   0   0   0
```

Now, apply the `merge`

```
df3 = df_train.merge(df, how = 'outer', on = ['Iteration','Player','Result'])

Out:
Iteration   Player  Result  cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4    cat9    cat8
0   1   0   23  0   0.0 1   0.0 NaN NaN
1   1   1   65  0   1.0 0   1.0 NaN NaN
2   4   2   34  1   0.0 0   0.0 NaN NaN
3   2   0   54  0   NaN 0   NaN 1.0 0.0
4   2   1   87  1   NaN 0   NaN 0.0 1.0
```

Comment: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: @SachinHegde Can you provide your sample data as text? Then I can test on my computer. From images I can't copy and paste

Comment: @SachinHegde Sorry, I should have also been more explicit. Replace your images in your questions for text data, can be the output of `df.head(3)` for example

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Updated the code again with the format you were looking for..

Comment: I was able to reproduce issue and have added actual code in the description

Comment: @SachinHegde Test my last suggestion. I add `on` condition in `merge`. If this don't work, I can't help you =/

Comment: it was the issue with pd dummies. your approach works,